# Adding MM::SS times, dividing them and printing the average

Tags: perl, datetime

Let's say I just ran for 10 km and I now have 10 1km split times in the form of MM::SS.  I want a simple way to add up an arbitrary number of the split times and average them.  For instance, maybe I want to see how much faster (or slower) the last 5 km were when compared with the first 5 km.

I can do this myself by parsing the times, dividing them into seconds and then converting them back to MM::SS.  The math isn't hard, but I was wondering if something on CPAN already does this in a simple way.  My first attempt was using DateTime, but it doesn't convert from seconds to minutes, because of leap seconds.

To be clear, I don't care about leap seconds in this context, but I'm curious as to whether a library exists.  As an example, here is what I have tried.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use DateTime::Format::Duration;

my $formatter = DateTime::Format::Duration->new( pattern => '%M:%S' );

my @splits = @ARGV;
my $split_number = @splits;

my $total = $formatter->parse_duration( shift @splits );

foreach my $split (@splits) {
    $total->add_duration(
        $formatter->parse_duration($split) );
}

say 'Total time: ' . join ':', $total->minutes, $total->seconds;

$total->multiply( 1 / $split_number );

say 'Average time: ' . join ':', $total->minutes, $total->seconds;
say 'Using DateTime::Format::Duration: ' . $formatter->format_duration( $total );
```

And a sample run:

```
$ perl script/add-splits.pl 1:30 2:30
Total time: 3:60
Average time: 1.5:30
Using DateTime::Format::Duration: 01:30
```

So, you can see that the duration object itself, gives me a correct answer, but not something that a human wants to decipher.

DateTime::Format::Duration tries to be helpful, but tosses out 30 seconds in the process.

I'm not looking for the raw code to do this.  I am interested in whether this already exists on CPAN.

Comment: There might be a bug in how DateTime::Format::Duration rolls up seconds into minutes...you may wish to file a bug ticket.

Comment: @xxfelixxx, thanks.  I had a chat with the author of DateTime and he suggested that multiplication by non-integer units should actually not be supported, so I've filed a bug against DateTime::Duration https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=117866&results=6ab71e8eea43129a0c4f4c5702e469f5

Comment: @oalders  Can you explain that? The problem that I see is not multiplication per se, but that  minutes cannot be converted to seconds, nor vice-versa.  So `3 (min)/2` has to return `1.5`. They say that in docs, both `DateTime` and `::Duration` (the link to that explanation is in my answer).  I got interested in this question and searched all date/time modules I know of or could find, and found nothing that can do sum/ave of `mm:ss` correctly. (Your `1:30` + `2:30` is a good test case for both.)

Comment: @zdim I will follow up with him and update here.

Comment: @zdim the issue as I now understand it is that in some cases multiplying by an integer will work, but not in all cases.  For instance, if you end up with a non-integer amount of seconds, that won't get converted to nanoseconds.  So there's a good chance of getting a broken value at some point.

Comment: @oalders  Ah, thank you -- that is an issue (bug) since the seconds (vs nano) conversions are claimed to work. Thank you for the update!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with finding this exact functionality on CPAN is that you want to manipulate strings that are time intervals.  Most modules are concerned with the context of such strings, working with them as *date* and *time*. So it's hard to find something that simply adds `mm:ss` format. Since this quest is rather specific, and simple to write, why not wrap it in your own package?

Having said that, see whether the snippet below fits what you are looking for.

---

This is a simple solution with the core module [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html). It does go to seconds to do the math, but it can be wrapped in a few subs that are then also easily extended for other calculations.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;
use POSIX 'strftime';
use List::Util 'sum';

my @times = @ARGV;

my $fmt = '%M:%S'; 

my $tot_sec = sum map { Time::Piece->strptime($_, $fmt)->epoch } @times;

my $ave_sec = sprintf("%.0f", $tot_sec/@times);  # round the average

my ($tot, $ave) = map { strftime $fmt, gmtime $_ } ($tot_sec, $ave_sec);

say "Total time:   $tot";
say "Average time: $ave";
```

For `manip_times.pl 2:30 1:30` this prints

```
Total time:   04:00
Average time: 02:00
```

We use `strptime` from `Time::Piece` to get the object, and then its `epoch` method returns seconds, which are added and averaged.  This is converted back to `mm:ss` using `strftime` from [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html). The `Time::Piece` also has `strftime` but to use it we'd have to have an object.

Note that `Time::Piece` does *subtract* its objects directly, `$t1 - $t2`, but it cannot add them.  One can add an integer (seconds) to an object though, `$t1 + 120`.  Also see the core [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html), a part of the distribution.

---

*Comments on the method used in the question*

The [DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edrolsky/DateTime-1.36/lib/DateTime/Duration.pm) objects that are used cannot convert between different units

> See the [How DateTime Math Works](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edrolsky/DateTime-1.36/lib/DateTime.pm#How_DateTime_Math_Works) section of the `DateTime.pm` documentation for more details. The short course: One cannot in general convert between seconds, minutes, days, and months, so this class will never do so.

From a bit further down the page, we see what conversions can be done and the related ones are only "*hours <=> minutes*" and "*seconds <=> nanoseconds*".  The reasons have to do with leap seconds, DST, and such.  Thus the calculation has to produce results such as `1.5` minutes.

---

The [Class::Date](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eszabgab/Class-Date-1.1.15/lib/Class/Date.pod) also looks suitable for these particular requirements.

Comment: @oalders I've updated my answer a bit, with more commentary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using the `DateTime` object.  Since it doesn't handle date parsing, we have to split the strings ourselves...

**add_splits.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use DateTime;

my @splits = @ARGV;
my $split_number = @splits;

my $fmt = "%M:%S";
my $total = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => 0 );

foreach my $split (@splits) {
    my ($split_min, $split_sec) = split /:/, $split;
    $total->add( minutes => $split_min, seconds => $split_sec );
}

say 'Total time: ' . $total->strftime($fmt);

my $avg_seconds = $total->epoch / $split_number;
my $avg = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => 0 )->add( seconds => $avg_seconds );

say 'Average time: ' . $avg->strftime($fmt);
```

**Output**

```
$ perl add_splits.pl 1:30 2:30
Total time: 04:00
Average time: 02:00
```

Comment: Both very helpful answers.  I accepted the first because it was the first one in, but this has also helped answer my question of whether there is an existing CPAN module which already does this simply.